# Not able to use blob storage operations using System Assigned Managed Identity in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

Getting **"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."** error while trying to use System Assigned Managed Identity in Azure using C# language.

The steps followed

- Created a new VM with Enabled Identity (System Assigned)
- Added the VM in IAM using Role Assignment in storage account
- Able to generate token using C#
- But getting exception while reading blob, below are the exception details

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<DownloadTextAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
```

The Program Class

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var blob = new AzureCloudBlob();
                Console.WriteLine(blob.ReadBlob());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

The AzureCloudBlob class, used to connect and read a blob using System Assigned Managed Idenitity access token

```
    class AzureCloudBlob
    {
        public CloudBlockBlob CreateConnection()
        {
            var token = GetToken();
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredential(token);
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredentials);
            var serviceUri = new Uri("https://mystorageacc.blob.core.windows.net/practice/blob.txt");

            return new CloudBlockBlob(serviceUri, storageCredentials);
        }

        public string ReadBlob()
        {
            var client = CreateConnection();
            var blobClient = client.DownloadTextAsync();
            var data = blobClient.Result;
            return data;
        }

        public string GetToken()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://management.azure.com/");
            request.Headers["Metadata"] = "true";
            request.Method = "GET";

            try
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var streamResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string stringResponse = streamResponse.ReadToEnd();
                var list = (Dictionary<string, string>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringResponse, typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
                string accessToken = list["access_token"];
                Console.WriteLine(accessToken);
                return accessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errorText = String.Format("{0} \n\n{1}", e.Message, e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "Acquire token failed");
                Console.WriteLine(errorText);
                return errorText;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access Azure storage with Azure AD auth, we should use `resouce=https://storage.azure.com/` to get Azure AD access token. But you use `resource=https://management.azure.com/`. Please replace it. Besides, please note that you need to assign right role to the MSI. The role should be **Storage Blob Data Reader**, **Storage Blob Data Contributor** or **Storage Blob Data Owner**.

The detailed steps are as below

1. Enable system-assigned managed identity on Azure VM

   ```
   $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name myVM
   Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -VM $vm -AssignIdentity:$SystemAssigned
   ```
2. Assign role to MSI on storage account scope

   ```
   $sp =Get-AzADServicePrincipal -displayname "<your VM name>"
   New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $sp.id `
       -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Reader" `
       -Scope  "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/sample-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>"
   ```
3. code

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           //get token
           string accessToken = GetMSIToken("https://storage.azure.com/");

           //create token credential
           TokenCredential tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);

           //create storage credentials
           StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

           Uri blobAddress = new Uri("<URI to blob file>");

           //create block blob using storage credentials
           CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobAddress, storageCredentials);

           //retrieve blob contents
           Console.WriteLine(blob.DownloadText());
           Console.ReadLine();
       }

       static string GetMSIToken(string resourceID)
       {
           string accessToken = string.Empty;
           // Build request to acquire MSI token
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=" + resourceID);
           request.Headers["Metadata"] = "true";
           request.Method = "GET";

           try
           {
               // Call /token endpoint
               HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

               // Pipe response Stream to a StreamReader, and extract access token
               StreamReader streamResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
               string stringResponse = streamResponse.ReadToEnd();
               JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
               Dictionary<string, string> list = (Dictionary<string, string>)j.Deserialize(stringResponse, typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
               accessToken = list["access_token"];
               return accessToken;
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               string errorText = String.Format("{0} \n\n{1}", e.Message, e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "Acquire token failed");
               return accessToken;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

[image]